# Difference between readonly keyword/Expression-bodied members in c#?, which is better?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

In c# readonly members can be reduced to readonly auto properties/expression-bodied members for immutable members is expression-bodied members are better then using readonly keywords?

Using readonly keywork:

```
public static readonly string  COMPANY_NAME= "XYZ";
```

Using Expression-bodied Members:

```
public  static  string  COMPANY_NAME => "XYZ";
```

I have come across various forums and solution that suggest expression bodied members for short hand use, and i could not find how it differs in performance.

Comment: In case of a string it´s fairly simple: use `const`. In all other cases: that´s up to your preferences and thus opinion-based. In particular the term "betetr" can means many different things. What do you mean by this?

Comment: Hi. Since comments and answers here indicate that you are in fact comparing apples and oranges, any answer to this question that tries to tell you that one is better than the other will be based on opinion and not fact, since neither is good at everything.

Comment: If you're worrying about the performance of reading a field like `COMPANY_NAME`, you should probably stop worrying about performance, and read [this](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) first, especially "part the third". There are reasons to pick a field over a property over a constant, and performance *can* be one of them, but performance should never be your *main reason* for making the choice before anything else in this case, because there are clear differences in semantics.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Let's dive deep and see what compiler does for different types of fields.

```
class Program
{
    public const string ConstString = "mesa const";
    public static readonly string ReadonlyStatic = "mesa readonly";
    public static string ExpressionBodied => "mesa expression";
    public static string GetInitialized {get;} =  "mesa get";
    public static string GetWithBody { get { return "mesa get"; } } 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        System.Console.WriteLine("readonly:" + ReadonlyStatic);
        System.Console.WriteLine("const:" + ConstString);
        System.Console.WriteLine("expression bodied:" + ExpressionBodied);
        System.Console.WriteLine("get initialized:" + GetInitialized);
        System.Console.WriteLine("get with body:" + GetWithBody);
    }
}
```

`const string` creates a `literal string` and will be evaluated at call site:

```
.field public static literal string ConstString = "mesa const"

// call site:
IL_0021: ldstr        "const:mesa const"
IL_0026: call         void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

`static readonly` creates a field that is initialized in ctor and means only one field reference when used:

```
.field public static initonly string ReadonlyStatic

// call site:
IL_000c: ldstr        "readonly:"
IL_0011: ldsfld       string readonly_props.Program::ReadonlyStatic
IL_0016: call         string [System.Runtime]System.String::Concat(string, string)
IL_001b: call         void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

Expression bodied member generates a getter, which returns constant value:

```
.method public hidebysig static specialname string 
get_ExpressionBodied() cil managed 
{
  .maxstack 8

  // [9 50 - 9 67]
  IL_0000: ldstr        "mesa expression"
  IL_0005: ret          
} // end of method Program::get_ExpressionBodied

// call site:
IL_002c: ldstr        "expression bodied:"
IL_0031: call         string readonly_props.Program::get_ExpressionBodied()
IL_0036: call         string [System.Runtime]System.String::Concat(string, string)
IL_003b: call         void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

Readonly property with initialization generates an additional backing field for the initializing value.

```
.field private static initonly string '<GetInitialized>k__BackingField'    
.method public hidebysig static specialname string 
  get_GetInitialized() cil managed 
{
  .custom instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() 
  = (01 00 00 00 )
  .maxstack 8
  // [10 46 - 10 50]
  IL_0000: ldsfld       string readonly_props.Program::'<GetInitialized>k__BackingField'
  IL_0005: ret          
} // end of method Program::get_GetInitialized

// call site:
IL_0041: ldstr        "get initialized:"
IL_0046: call         string readonly_props.Program::get_GetInitialized()
IL_004b: call         string [System.Runtime]System.String::Concat(string, string)
IL_0050: call         void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

A Property getter with full body is a bit longer:

```
.method public hidebysig static specialname string 
  get_GetWithBody() cil managed 
{
  .maxstack 1
  .locals init (
    [0] string V_0
  )

  // [11 48 - 11 49]
  IL_0000: nop          

  // [11 50 - 11 68]
  IL_0001: ldstr        "mesa get"
  IL_0006: stloc.0      // V_0
  IL_0007: br.s         IL_0009

  // [11 69 - 11 70]
  IL_0009: ldloc.0      // V_0
  IL_000a: ret          

} // end of method Program::get_GetWithBody

// call site:
IL_0056: ldstr        "get with body:"
IL_005b: call         string readonly_props.Program::get_GetWithBody()
IL_0060: call         string [System.Runtime]System.String::Concat(string, string)
IL_0065: call         void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

From that, we can order them by amount of code (and calls) they generate:

- `const string` is definitely the fastest one, but can cause unexpected behavior in case of change, when used from other assembiles (as other answers mentioned)
- `static readonly` comes right behind, with one field access
- `static string ExpressionBodied => "xxx"` will cause a method call (getter) that simply returns a constant
- `static string GetInitialized {get;} = "xxx"` will result in a method call and a field access
- `static string GetWithBody { get { return "xxx"; } }` will cause a method call that returns a constant, but wih additional memory allocation, it would seem

In practice, the performance differences will probably be unobservable. As pointed out, IL code can be further optimized by JIT, so you can end up with effectively the same performance. 
Nevertheless, I prefer to go with option 1. or 2.

Comment: Keep in mind, that what you see in IL can be quite misleading, as modern JIT does most of the heavy lifting. What you end up with after JITting can very vaguely resemble what you are observing in IL. In particular a getter returning a constant string can be JITted in the same code that a constant string without any getter. Because of this, rating them "by amount of code" is not very useful.

Comment: I believe the extra cost going on in the GetWithBody property is from debug compilation. That looks to me like compiler optimizations turned off.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh good point, I added such remark to the answer.

Comment: @RichardRobertson I suspect so, but in `Release` configuration it looked the same (although I didn't investigate further, maybe I missed something)

Comment: @qbik Oh that is interesting. But Andrew is still right about the jitter still turning it into almost a direct constant read.

Comment: keep in mind that expressionbodied => "xxx" will be evaluated EACH TIME. https://blog.somewhatabstract.com/2015/08/25/c6-auto-property-initializers-and-expression-bodied-properties/

Answer (score 10):

First, you should use `const` with `string` constants, not `readonly`. You should use the latter only for objects requiring a constructor call to construct them.

There is a side note to this though, as stated in comments, you should be aware that constants will be optimized even across assemblies (so your library constants can also be evaluated as constants on compile time by the referenced library). That would mean that with minor version updates, you could end up with another constant value in the assembly than in your library. In such cases you should keep using `static readonly`.

Second, there is a huge difference between `static readonly` fields and `static` properties. The `static` properties will get evaluated each and every time you call it. The `static readonly` is slightly optimized, since it does only do a single assignment.

Answer (score 8):

In this case, the overall *results* will appear the same, but realise that they are quite different.

The first defines a `readonly` field. The initialization expression to the right of the `=` runs once, and the field always returns that value.

The second defines a `get`-only property. The expression to the right of the `=>` will be evaluated *each time* it is accessed.

In this case, your expressions are deterministic and produce immutable objects. If neither of these were true, then the difference between them would be observable (by the second returning different results or by being able to modify the contents of the first)